# using Axios - I need to set Request Payload Instead of Form Data - When I set Content Type = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

Tags: reactjs, axios

I need to set Request Payload Instead of Form Data using Axios - When I set Content Type = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

And when I am using Content-Type = 'application/json' - I am getting 400 Status code

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://github.com/axios/axios#axioscreateconfig) it should be set in configuration, before the dispatching of the request.

So:

```
// ES5:
const axios = require('axios');
// ES6:
import axios from 'axios';

const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://foo.bar/endpoint',
  timeout: 1000, // Not really relevant, but was in the example
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
});
// Post or get...
instance.get().then(...);
```

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config) is the rest of the documentation for axios request config.

Comment: I checked with Removing - baseURL: 'http://foo.bar/endpoint', Was Working